# Behavior of the extern keyword in C

Tags: c, extern

I read about global variables in `C`. I have two questions about the `extern` keyword.

1. Why is initialization required for variables that are declared globally *with* the `extern` keyword?
2. Why is initialization not required for variables that declared globally *without* the `extern` keyword?

Please explain the difference.

Comment: Are you sure about your definitions? Most often, `extern SomeType some_variable;` is used without an initialization in a header file to declare the variable, and `SomeType some_variable = { … };` is used to define and initialize the variable in one source file. That seems to be the opposite of what you're claiming. See [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c/) for the nitty-gritty details. Stop reading at one of the two earlier stopping points (you'll see).

Comment: initialization is *not* required for an `extern` variable.  an `extern` variable is explicitly *not* defined in this file, but is instead a reference to a variable defined in some other object file that will be linked with this one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Why is initialization required for variables that are declared globally with `extern`?

   ```
   // declarations  
   extern int foo1;
   extern int foo2;
   ```

Initialization is **not required**.  Global variables lacking explicit initialization are initialized as below.

*Declaring* a variable does not *define* it.  In some unit, the variable, if used, needs to be *defined*.

2. Why is initialization not required for variables that declared globally without `extern`?

   ```
   // declaration and definition - no initialization
   int foo3;  // Same functional effect as int foo3 = 0;
   // declaration and definition - with initialization
   int foo4 = 5;
   ```

Global variables lacking explicit initialization are initialized as below.

---

C11dr 6.7.9 Initialization

... If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:

— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
— if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Comment: @M.M Initialization details added.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is initialization required for variables that are declared
>   globally with the extern keyword?

When we use **extern** keyword with **uninitialized variable** compiler think variable has initialized somewhere else in the program. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int i;    //extern variable
int main()
{
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
 undefined reference to `i'
```

**because**, memory is not allocated for these variable. Hence in second case compiler is showing error unknown symbol i. That's why **allocate the memory for extern variables it is necessary to initialize the variables**. Like,

```
extern int i;
int i = 10;
```

> Why is initialization not required for variables that declared
>   globally without the extern keyword?

When we don't use **extern** keyword then compiler initialized it with default value. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i;    //By default it is extern variable
int main()
{
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

because, **Compiler will automatically initialize with default value to extern variable**.